# Php without start/end tags?

Tags: php

Is it possible to have php not to require the begin/end tags (`<?php ?>`) for some of the files?
The code should be interpreted as php by default.

I'm aware that I can leave out the end tag (`?>`).

Comment: is there a specific reason that you dont want to do this?

Comment: Where did you pick up that you can leave out the end tag? Never heard of this before.

Comment: This is not a sane default behavior.  Don't do it.

Comment: @e.c.ho : just try ^^ you'll see it works (as long as you don't want any non-php code at the end of your file) ;; it is also recommended by coding standard of several frameworks (like Zend Framework, for instance) -- the point being that you cannot have white-spaces after the closing tag if there is no end tag.

Comment: @seengee In a MVC structure, the code looks ugly inside the controllers/models. I know it's not a big deal, but I've been coding php for 4 years, yet it it always felt wrong.

Comment: Everyone seems to be making the assumption that this is for web programming. PHP is quite usable as a general purpose scripting language as well. In that context the tags aren't always as useful.

Comment: +1 This is a good question. The open/close tags force a blending of display and logic. There is a proposal: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nophptags

Comment: good question. if it is a `.php` file wile require an opening `<?php` ? the first line should be `declare(strict_types=1);` if there is some literal html or javascript or image data in it there should be a closing `?>` or a `printf` or an `echo`. The `<?php` is redundant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. The interpreter needs the tags to know what to parse and what not to.

Comment: To add this this answer, anything outside of PHP tags is simply sent to the browser as text. PHP was originally intended as a templating language, whereby the PHP tags are interspersed with HTML, not the other way round.

Comment: Fair but a `.php` extension signals to a server to call a php interpreter anyhow.

Answer (score 18):

If you'd like to call your PHP script from the command line, you can leave the script tags using the `-r` switch. Extract from `man php`:

> ```
>    -r code        Run PHP code without using script tags ’<?..?>’
> ```

Now you can invoke your script in the following manner:

```
php -r "$(cat foo.php)"
```

Comment: Then why this line `php -r 'echo "Hello World!\n";'` always throws error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''echo' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
expecting end of file in Command line code on line 1` ?

Comment: @VickyDev not sure, it still works for me (PHP 7.1.16). What platform/version do you have?

Comment: Windows 7 64Bit and PHP 7.1.x stable, but it never works the way I mentioned, even-though, it has no syntax errors.

Answer (score 7):

It's better to not use end tag. Begin tag is neccesary.

As MaoTseTongue mentioned, in Zend documentation there is written:

> For files that contain only PHP code, the closing tag ("?>") is never permitted. It is not required by PHP, and omitting it´ prevents the accidental injection of trailing white space into the response.

Comment: I've heard this before, and I'm curious as to what? Is it to do with blank space at the end of the file causing problems (e.g. sending output before headers have been sent etc).

Comment: errr... by 'what' I meant 'why', sorry!

Comment: Do not include the closing php tag prevents "the accidental injection of trailing white space into the response". (see the [Zend Framework Documentation][1]).


  [1]: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.htm

Comment: It's fine to use the end tag (and aesthetically pleasing to those who like balance in their tags). The key point is not to include any trailing whitespace (eg. carriage return, line feed, tab, space, etc.) after the closing php tag because the web server will actually send those characters to the browser. Even then, for most web applications serving html, xml, json, it's generally harmless. But it can cause problems when dynamically building binary data such as an image. Another time it gets you into trouble is setting http headers when your php code has accidentally already sent whitespace.

Comment: just as empty lines before an `<!doctyp html>` might be a problem. Lets file a RFC

Answer (score 0):

Likewise you could make a text file that has a .php extension, and use another, 'real' php file to load that file, such as

### Fake PHP file

```
php_info();
```

### Real PHP file

```
<?
// file_contents returns a string, which can be processed by eval()
eval(file_get_contents('/path/to/file/'.urldecode($_GET['fakefile'])));
?>
```

In addition, you could use some mod_rewrite trickery to make the web user feel like they are browsing the php file itself (e.g. http://example.com/fakefile.php)

### .htaccess file:

```
RewrieEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ realfile.php?fakefile=$1 [QSA]
```

However, if I remember correctly, your processing will be a little slower, and there are some issues with how `eval`ed code handles `$GLOBALS`, `$_SERVER`, `$_POST`, `$_GET`, and other vars.  You will have to make a global variable to pass these super globals into your evaluated code.

For example:

```
<?
global $passed_post = $_POST;
// only by converting $_POST into a global variable can it be understood by eval'ed code. 
eval("global $passed_post;\n print_r($passed_post);");
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store PHP code in a file or database (without `<?php ?>`) and then activate it using `eval()`. Notice, the code will perform slower. An `eval()` example comes here:

```
// Data layer (array, database or whatever).
$arr = array("a","b","c");

// Code layer - hint: you can get the code from a file using file_get_contents().
$str = 'foreach($arr as $v) { echo $v . " "; }';

// Shake + Bake
eval($str);
```

Result: a b c